# How to average a stack of images together using Pillow?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'd like to stack several images and just average them together (set opacity to 1/n for each image in the stack).

How can I do this with Python? I'm guessing Pillow is going to be helpful, but I haven't found any functionality like this, yet. What should I be looking for?

Comment: You may be right. I'm surprised that it didn't show up in my searches. That being said it seems over-engineered. Casting images to arrays of floats in order to combine them feels... gross. Does PIL/Pillow not have native ways to merge two images?

Comment: Regardless... that other question is probably where the conversation should continue anyway ;-)

Comment: You can merge 2 images with `Image.blend(im1, im2, 0.5)` i'm not aware of any native way to average.